# How to connect to the proper MySQL database on OS X? (Two mysqld instances running)

Tags: php, mysql, macos, mamp

I have two instances of MySQL server running on my machine. One is the mysql package that came bundled with MAMP, and the other is a 64 bit installation that I downloaded so I could work with a python library of mine.

This is strictly for development.

Both are running:

```
:~ zachary$ ps -awwx | grep mysql
 1944 ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/MyMachine-2.local.pid
 2016 ??         0:10.17 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/MyMachine-2.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/MyMachine-2.local.pid
 6824 ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=8889 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --lower_case_table_names=0 --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log
 6894 ??         0:00.36 /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --datadir=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql --user=mysql --lower_case_table_names=0 --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --port=8889
```

Yet my PHP only seems to want to be able to connect to MAMP's MySQL server. I believe that mysql_connect() lets you specify a port but I'm not sure how to deal with this.

Thanks.

Edit: it seems that MAMP has a preference for its own MySQL server when you use mysql_connect() on a MAMP installation -- not sure why -- can anyone please explain? But I was able to connect to my manually installed MySQL server using this syntax:

```
mysql_connect(':/tmp/mysql.sock', 'username', 'pw');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like MAMP is running on port 8889 and the other instance is on the default port (3306).  To be sure, run `netstat -lnp` to see what ports all listening processes are using. (Warning:  double check the options to netstat, as I am a Linux user, not a Mac user).

Comment: @Zachary Burt - from Linux man page:   -l, --listening Show only listening sockets.  --numeric , -n Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names.   -p, --program Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.

Answer (score 1):

AJ right.
And to connect to MySQL server on specific port (other than 3306)

```
mysql_connect("{$mysqlServerNameOrIp}:{$mysqlSpecificServerPort}", 'username', 'password');
```

Comment: You had a syntax error that I fixed per the function documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php